# Is there a difference between removed and deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, wording

Recently I noticed change in my reputation on stackoverflow and after further investigation it seems that one of my questions was "removed". Here is an entry from reputation history:

> **-3** yesterday
>   **-3** 06:58 **removed** When to use 32bit mode for shared memory in devices of compute capability 3.0+?

Couple question related to this:

- How can question become "removed"? I've read about [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) but it does not seem to be this case because:

  > Deleted questions will also always be visible to their authors

  But that is not my case, can't "click" the question in my reputation history, nor it can be viewed in "deleted recent questions", so where am I supposed to see it?
- The next question is - why was my question removed at all? Is it because of the:

  > ... may also be removed, as well as **questions which have no significant activity over a very long period after being asked**.

  Have to say it does not seem very fortunate to delete clear and on topic question just because of inactivity ...

Comment: [here is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713943/when-to-use-32bit-mode-for-shared-memory-in-devices-of-compute-capability-3-0) - as the OP you can still view it, though not the answer. It was removed by automatic cleanup process, since it did not have a positive score or answers with positive score, hence considered not worth keeping.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks, the hyperlink works, but how am I supposed to get to it via my available UI actions and not directly like this? Hmm, I see, definitely no positive score on that one and I was fighting for it to be resurrected already once or twice and even though moderator considered my reasoning valid, it did not receive any new upvote so this is going on and on.

Comment: Well, one of the most popular declined feature requests is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) - more than enough reading about the subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference: "deleted" and "removed" are used synonymously. The question was deleted according to the rules stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Since it was a year old, it did not appear in the list "deleted recent questions", which has the deleted questions that were *created* at most 60 days ago.

The reputation history with "show removed posts" appears to follow peculiar logic when decided whether to link the posts:

- If you have enough reputation to see deleted posts (10K on graduated sites), all of them are linked
- If you don't, only your own deleted **answers** are linked. Your own **questions**, and posts by others are not.

Illustrated by my reputation history here, where I don't have 10K yet:

[image]

Comment: Related report: [In reputation history, own deleted answers are linked but own deleted questions are not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261029)

Comment: Thanks for starting a bug report, voted it up.

Comment: I was just wondering how it all went with a bug report as I am still unable to "click" my own deleted question, but it appers the report was deleted meanwhile and the above provided link is no longer valid.